# Ubuntu 20.10 auto uninstalled

Tags: package-management, 20.04, kernel, uninstall, 20.10

Left my laptop locked last night. Woken it up to unlock it and it ended showing constant automatic unlock failure. Decided to reboot by a hard shutdown on the power button since I was unable to do anything at the login screen. When it booted back up it booted into 20.04 with 20.10 gone like a fart in the wind. I can't recall what was the last running kernel but the current one is 5.8.0-25-generic and checking version by running `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 5.8.0-25-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.35.1) #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:30:38 UTC 2020.
```

I also ran `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` commands and got this output:

```
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-121-generic                   4.15.0-121.123                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-193-generic                    4.4.0-193.224                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic                     4.4.0-31.50                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic                     5.4.0-52.57                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.7.0-15-generic                     5.7.0-15.16                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-25-generic                     5.8.0-25.26                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-26-generic                     5.8.0-26.27                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic               4.4.0-31.50                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-unsigned-5.10.0-051000rc1-generic    5.10.0-051000rc1.202010291359              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-unsigned-5.10.0-051000rc1-lowlatency 5.10.0-051000rc1.202010291359              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-26-generic            5.8.0-26.27                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

which leads me to believe that I could have accidentally changed something when I was uninstalling some software package and the last thing I removed was Evolution email client for which I used the following set of commands:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove evolution evolution-exchange evolution-plugins evolution-common evolution-webcal`

Then I ran `sudo rm /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution`
to be sure everything related to it is removed.

Then I also ran `sudo apt-get purge evolution` to really be sure it is all gone since some other app gave me indicators some traces are still there (it was during the KMail install process). I then ran `dpkg -l|grep -i evolution` and eventually removed anything and everything related to evolutions running the previous command.

Could have any of this caused that when I rebooted I booted into 20.04?

Comment: You have a partially installed kernel. Run `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, your suggestion only added 5.8.0-33-generic
 and removed the 5.8.0-25-generic but the 20.10 is gone and software update as suggested by ubuntu is not picking up the upgrade unless I run it manually, which I don't want to do.

cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.8.0-33-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-036) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.35.1) #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 09:14:40 UTC 2020

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did afterward since the initial kernel reinstall didn't do anything, or at least it didn't produce the needed results.

I ran the following command to remove GNOME altogether because I figured maybe if I remove the window management part it could only help since there will be less dependencies:

```
sudo apt purge adwaita-icon-theme gedit-common gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-characters gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces gnome-desktop3-data gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-getting-started-docs-ru gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-logs gnome-mahjongg gnome-menus gnome-mines gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-startup-applications gnome-sudoku gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-extra-data gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-user-docs gnome-user-docs-ru gnome-video-effects language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base language-pack-gnome-ru language-pack-gnome-ru-base language-selector-gnome libgail18 libgail18 libgail-common libgail-common libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgnome-games-support-common libgnomekbd8 libgnomekbd-common libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-todo libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libpam-gnome-keyring libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal pinentry-gnome3 yaru-theme-gnome-shell
```

Then, I ran `autopurge` command as to `sudo apt autopurge`.
Next, I ran `desktop install` again with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` command followed with `update` and `upgrade commands`, and finally with a `sudo reboot` and when it booted it booted into 20.10/

Now, how stable is it? I don't know as I am still checking it all. If I find anything unusual, I will post further comments.